# Should published npm packages contain docs directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have one repo that uses many other of my repositories and I want to generate docs with jsdoc in them. I'm considering ignoring the `docs/` directory in the `.npmignore` to cut the sizes of each package as it may get really big in the end.

Is it good or bad to do such kind of thing? As far as I understand it's good to have docs in the package as anyone working on the code can check it without leaving the IDE/editor but on the other hand the size of the `node_modules/` may grow a bunch when you have lots of dependencies with the documentation.

Comment: I would recommend  that don't put docs in the package. As you said it will increase the package size and honestly I don't think anybody looks for documentation in node_modules directory